# Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a little problem with my Ubuntu system.

When selecting boot on startup for a harddrive, the partition can't be mounted. The error which occurs is as follows:

```
dmesg | tail 
[  470.027891] EXT4-fs (sda2): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
```

The corresponding `/etc/fstab` entry is:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d0e8607e-9067-49c9-929e-83ec7f70cea1 /mnt/d0e8607e-9067-49c9-929e-83ec7f70cea1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Also in the GUI:

[image: Unable to mount]

[image: Error while mounting]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Short version:**

You're not using the parameter as it was designed.  Use `comment=x-gvfs-show` instead of `x-gvfs-show`...

**Long version:**

- Don't use the GUI but edit your `fstab` manually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and typing:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```
- find the offending line that shows `x-gvfs-show` and type `comment=` in front of it
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- <kbd>S</kbd>ave
- <kbd>Y</kbd>es
- reload all entries in `fstab`:

  ```
  mount -a
  ```

(Or if you just moved over from Windows: don't type `mount -a` and just reboot for old times' sake)  **;-)**

Comment: I guess him didn't use the command, just copied from dmesg. It's a mistake of the mount commands of Nautilus or a fail with the drive. This message is shown, but we don't know where to chage it's value.

Comment: @erm3nda: edited question to make it more beginner-friendly!  **;-)**

Comment: Okey, fixed fstab with your suggestion. Someone didn't pay attention to that :) right? Thank you.

Comment: Can this answer be improved with instructions on how to manually mount the drive without having to boot from a live cd or usb in order to edit /etc/fstab?

Comment: @Simón: Better now? (It only took me a year and 2 days to finally do as you requested)

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would add this here.

I recently switched one of my pc's from Ubuntu to Xubuntu (not with a clean install).

My external USB hard drives would no longer automount. Checking in gnome-disks they were set to automount but did not.

So I switched to manual mounting (which generates entries in /etc/fstab). The manual mount options were automatically populated with x-gvfs-show (no "comment="), which resulted in a failure to mount.

What I'm suggesting is that the fstab entries with x-gvfs-show may not have been manually generated.

Comment: I can confirm this. I formatted and mounted a partition through the GUI and it added this option causing a failure to boot at mount.